# how to keep only specific line in function of value and colum

Tags: array-formulas

I have a table like it :

```
segment   segment_detail      Turnover

A                              300

B                              1000
B         bbb                  400
B         bbbb                 600

C                              543
C         ccder                250
C         ccc                  293
```

the first line is the total of segment_detail,  for example,  for segment B, you have bbb  and bbbb who is equal at 400+600.

I Would like to have something like this :

```
segment   segment_detail      Turnover

A                              300

B         bbb                  400
B         bbbb                 600


C         ccder                250
C         ccc                  293
```

So I want delete the line who correspond at total  only if you have element in segment_detail.
For example, the first line  with segment 'A' must stay because it's the unique row 'A' and we have no detail for 'A'.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=FILTER(A:C, (B:B <> "") + ISNA(MATCH(A:A, UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, B:B <> "")),)))
```

[image]